# How to perform star rating using django and ajax?

Tags: ajax, django

I want to perform a star rating in my blog application for better user experience...But couldn't perform in django using ajax...I basically don't want to use any third party application for my blog project...I want to do manually using django and ajax...

This is my blog model:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='likes',blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    blog_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_image', null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(categories,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='blogs')
    blog_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Any idea anyone how to perform this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You'll need to write some code to do that.

Comment: Yeah I know that...Can you provide me some link which solves my query?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're trying to rate the blog 1-5.

If you want to save each and every vote for the blog, you'll have to keep an additional model for the votes, something like:

```
class BlogStars(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stars = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

For each and every vote, you'll save the user, the blog voted for and the amount of stars.

After that, all you need to do is to query the BlogStars:

```
stars = BlogStars.objects.filter(blog=my_blog).aggregate(Avg('stars'))
```

Saving the data using Ajax, is just making ajax calls to the backend view.
In any case, check this [tutorial](https://makitweb.com/5-star-rating-system-with-jquery-ajax-and-php/) as an example, although it uses PHP, it'll give you a good idea.